# How to get Image from directory path in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to retrieve image which i have it's path in phone

```
filepath = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.CommunicatorEye/files/Pictures/EmployeesCards/IMG_20190131_143513.jpg";

var image = DependencyService.Get<IDependency().RetriveImageFromLocation(filepath);
```

**IDependency.cs**

```
 public interface IDependency
    {
        Task<Image> RetriveImageFromLocation(string location);
    }
```

**Android** 
**DependencyImplementation.cs**

```
public async Task<Image> RetriveImageFromLocation(string location)
        {
            Image image = new Image();
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            using (var source = System.IO.File.OpenRead(location))
            {
                await source.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
            }

            image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => memoryStream);
            return image;
        }
```

but it doesn't work for me , any sample ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that file is within your app's sandbox, there is no reason to use DI/DependencyService/etc... to obtain a stream to populate an `ImageSource` and then add that to an `Image`.

Use an `FileImageSource` (static `ImageSource.FromFile`) and supply it the path:

```
var image = new Image
{
    Source = ImageSource.FromFile(filePath)
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by app sandbox , anyway this path in internal storage in phone so i want to get this image by image path

Comment: @AmrKamal app sandbox are files within your app, not ones external to your app, so assuming `com.CommunicatorEye` is your app, you can use my answer, no DependencyService is needed...

Comment: @AmrKamal Glad to help 

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get path of resources. `keys` should be declared in `App.xaml` file

```
public static String GetImagePath(string AppResourceName)
 {
   return (Application.Current.Resources[AppResourceName] as FileImageSource).File;
 }

public static Color GetColor(string AppResourceName)
 {
   return  (Color)Application.Current.Resources[AppResourceName];
 }
```